# How Do I Uninstall Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I installed Google Chrome long ago. It works. Today Google won't let me log in using the Linux machine running Elementary but it will let me log on with my Chromebook. I've changed passwords all over the place. Still it won't let me log in because it claims there is malicious software on the machine. Yet it will let me log in with a different Google account. If anybody knows what is going on let me know.

Google Chrome is not visible in the Installed Programs page. I want to delete it and reinstall it to see if this fixes the problem. I don't know where to go to uninstall it. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try https://askubuntu.com/questions/67047/how-to-uninstall-google-chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable -y` in the terminal